# How to show error messages in template after becameInvalid method

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm using Ember.js to display a list of customers. Inside this template, I have a modal to create new customers. Now, when creating invalid customers (e.g. duplicate name), the errors should be shown in the template. How can I get this to work?

**model**

```
Docket.Customer = DS.Model.extend({
  name:        DS.attr('string'),
  initial:     DS.attr('string'),
  description: DS.attr('string'),
  errors: {},
  becameInvalid: function(errors) {
    this.set('errors', errors.get('errors'));
    console.log(this.get('errors'));
  }
});
```

**console output**

[image]

**template**

```
<h1>Customers<button data-uk-modal="{target:'#customer-modal'}" class="icon-plus">New customer</button></h1>

    <div id="customer-modal" class="uk-modal">
        <div class="uk-modal-dialog uk-modal-dialog-slide">
            <a class="uk-modal-close uk-close"></a>
            <form class="uk-form" {{action "save" on="submit"}}>
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>New customer</legend>
                    <div class="uk-form-row">
                        {{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="name" name="name" class="uk-width-1-1" placeholder="Name" required="" }}
                        {{#if errors}}foo{{/if}}
                        {{#if errors.name}}{{errors.name}}{{/if}}
                    </div>
                    <div class="uk-form-row">
                        {{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="initial" name="initial" class="uk-width-1-1" placeholder="Initial" required="" }}
                    </div>
                    <div class="uk-form-row">
                        {{view Ember.TextArea valueBinding="description" name="description" class="uk-width-1-1" placeholder="Description"}}
                    </div>
                    <div class="uk-form-row">
                        <button type="submit" class="icon-check">Save</button>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

    <ul class="entries">
    {{#each}}
       <li>
           <div class="actions">
               <button {{action "remove" id}} class="icon-close"></button>
           </div>
           <div class="link" {{action "edit" id}} data-uk-modal="{target:'#customer-modal'}">
                <span class="initial">{{initial}}</span>{{name}}
            </div>
       </li>
    {{else}}
        <li>No customers</li>
    {{/each}}
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out:

**setup**

- Ember 1.2.0
- Ember Data 1.0.0-beta.4+canary.7af6fcb0
- Handlebars 1.1.2 runtime

**model**

```
Docket.Customer = DS.Model.extend({
  name:        DS.attr('string'),
  initial:     DS.attr('string'),
  description: DS.attr('string'),
  number:      DS.attr('string'),
  archived:    DS.attr('boolean')
});
```

**controller**

```
var _this = this;

// Create new record
var customer = this.store.createRecord('customer', data);

// Check for server errors (422) when saving
customer.save().then(function(){
  _this.resetAndCloseForm(form);
}, function(response){
  _this.set('errors',response.errors);
});
```

**route**

```
model: function() {
  this.store.find('customer');
  return this.store.filter('customer', function(customer) {

    // prevent Ember to insert new elements to the DOM if they are invalid
    // .get('isValid') returns always true, I think this is a bug, so I'm checking the ID
    return customer.get('id')
  })
}
```

**template**

```
{{#if errors}}{{errors.name}}{{/if}}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should consider moving your validations to the `controller`. Form validations and validations in general are very contextual. `Customer` model might have different set of validations depending on which part of your app you're in.

If you decide to move validations to the `controller`, you would need to create an observer that is going to watch the changes of a particular property/properties and run validations accordingly.

Note: I'm talking about client side validations (doesn't involve talking to the server before validations conditions are met), not server side ones.

```
App.CustomerController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  errors: [],
  runNameValidation: function() {
    // run validations for 'name'
    // if validations fail, push error to 'errors' array
    // on the controller
  }.observes('model.name')
});
```

There's a [validations library](https://github.com/dockyard/ember-validations) that takes care of it for you (it abstracts out validations bit and wraps it into a validations mixin for better reuse). Also, if you use for form specifically, you should consider looking at [easyForm](https://github.com/dockyard/ember-easyForm).

Update:

If you want to use server side validations, then all you need to add to your template is:

```
{{model.errors}}
```

When you try to save ED model and it server fails to do it, `model` is going to have `errors` array which you can use. Also, I would suggest creating the `errors` component, instead of creating the `errors` helper.

Comment: Thanks, but I need this method in my model cause its the only way to watch 422 errors from my API. Or should I call a controller method in my model if `becameInvalid` gets triggered?

Comment: You likely should observe `becameInvalid` state of the model and trigger an action on the controller level.

Comment: But how can I call the `runNameValidation` method from the model? And can I combine multiple validations in one observer?

Comment: you don't need to run `runNameValidation` from your model. `runNameValidation` is an observer the is fired any time the property on the model is changed.

Comment: I tried adding {{customer.errors}} to my template, but this doesnt change anything.

Comment: The only thing that worked is to put `{{#if errors}}{{errors.name}}{{/if}}` inside the `each` loop, but I need this message only once in the form.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a custom handlebars helper, like the following:

```
Ember.Handlebars.helper('show-errors', function(errors) {
    var html = '';
    if (errors) {        
        html += '<ul>';
        $.each(errors, function(key, values) {
            html += '<li>' + key + ' - ' + values.join(',') + '</li>'
        });
        html += '</ul>'
    }    
    return html.htmlSafe();
})
```

So just use `{{show-errors recordInstance.errors}}` in some template to use it.

In the first moment, there isn't errors so nothing will be displayed. When your record has a error, `errors` hash will be populed and the template will be updated.

Give a look in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/marciojunior/vh6aL/

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't worked for me (don't know why). But I figured it out (see the answer below) :)